# How to rotate a combined physics body with its center : corona SDK

Tags: android, rotation, physics, coronasdk

I  am doing a physics app with corona SDK. In that, I am creating a combined physics body with joints. What I need is : 'I need to rotate the new combined body with its center'. I am giving the code. Anyone please help...

```
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  local physics = require( "physics" )
  physics.start()
  physics.setDrawMode("debug")
  ---------------------------
     -- Creating bodies --
  ---------------------------
  local body_1 = display.newRect(0,0,40,40)
  local body_2 = display.newRect(0,0,40,40)
  local body_3 = display.newRect(0,0,40,40)
  local base_1 = display.newRect(0,display.contentHeight,display.contentWidth,display.contentHeight)
  body_1.x = 100; body_1.y = 250;
  body_2.x = 100; body_2.y = 300;
  body_3.x = 150; body_3.y = 275;

  ---------------------------
     -- Adding Physics --
  ---------------------------
  physics.addBody( body_1, { density=1.6, friction=0.5, bounce=0.0} )
  physics.addBody( body_2, { density=1.6, friction=0.5, bounce=0.0} )
  physics.addBody( body_3, { density=1.6, friction=0.5, bounce=0.02, radius = 20} )
  physics.addBody( base_1, "static", { density=1.6, friction=0.5, bounce=0.2} )

  ---------------------------
     -- Creating Joints --
  ---------------------------
  local myJoint_1 = physics.newJoint( "weld", body_1, body_2, 100,250 )
  local myJoint_2 = physics.newJoint( "pivot", body_1, body_3, 100,250 )
  local myJoint_2 = physics.newJoint( "pivot", body_2, body_3, 100,300 )

  ---------------------------
      -- My Function --
  ---------------------------
  local function rotateTheGroup()
       -- I want to rotate the combined body here. And I need to know the newBodie's referencepoint.
  end
 Runtime:addEventListener("tap",rotateTheGroup)
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you need help *rotating a body around an axis?* or choosing the axis?

Comment: @Beta : Hi, I need to rotate the body around its axis.

Comment: All right, we can simplify the problem to rotating a simple body around an axis (and do that for each of the three elements of the combined body). This appears to be 2D, so the problem is: given a body, an angle and a point, find the new location (`x` and `y`) of the body after we rotate it by that angle around that point. Is that correct?

Comment: @Beta : Yep. Here, I need to rotate the whole body with respect to it,s center. If you have any clue, please clarify.     Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the simple body **B** is located at (x<sub>b</sub>, y<sub>b</sub>), and the axis point **C** is at (x<sub>b</sub>, y<sub>b</sub>), and you want to rotate **B** around **C** by angle t (counter-clockwise), **B** goes to

**B'** = (x<sub>c</sub>+(x<sub>b</sub>-x<sub>c</sub>)cos(t)-(y<sub>b</sub>-y<sub>c</sub>)sin(t), y<sub>c</sub>+(x<sub>b</sub>-x<sub>c</sub>)sin(t)+(y<sub>b</sub>-y<sub>c</sub>)cos(t))

You can express this more concisely in matrix notation:

B' = **C** + **R**(**B**-**C**)

where

```
R = cos(t) -sin(t)
    sin(t)  cos(t)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dude. But, I'm sorry for what I've mentioned in the previous comments. That is: I've to rotate the whole body with it's axis. But I don't know how to find the new axis of the combined body(say X), and how to rotate the bodies as a whole around the axis 'X'. :(

Comment: Are you comfortable with vectors? With matrices? Do you see what I mean about rotating **B** around **C**? Do you see to rotate several points (**B1**, **B2**, **B3**...) around **C**? Are you having trouble choosing a center of rotation (a.k.a. axis)? Are you looking for the center of gravity?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Beta, But I've found a solution for this. I just used the following code to give the body an angular Impulse and applying it continuously, I got the work done.

```
  body_3:applyAngularImpulse( -1000 )
```

Thanks for the support guys.